# windows sockets, udp and udp replies different addresses

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, udp, winsock2

I have a problem with UDP messages under Python3 on Windows10.
The UDP messages are a command/response scheme.

- Example:  CMD_TURN_ON_LIGHT_BULB, Bulb #4
- Response: RSP_TURN_ON_LIGHT_BULB, Bulb #4 - OK.

My local Windows PC address is:  10.1.1.10

In all cases, the netmask here is 255.255.255.0

The remote device has 2 network addresses.
There are various routers between the PC and the remote device.

Device Address (A) is 10.2.2.10 (and is the "default route").

Device Address (B) is 10.3.3.10 (it is a backup interface)

**Case 1: This works.**

PC sends UDP to 10.2.2.10 (it uses "sendto()")
The remote device responds to the source address using sendto()

The PC receives the response, and the application receives the response.
The PC has a pending/waiting "recvfrom()"

**Case 2: This does not work.**

PC Sends UDP to 10.3.3.10 (the backup interface)
The remote device replies -
However - due to default route rules, the device replies from 10.2.2.10

The PC receives the reply (I see the reply/response in Wireshark)
The PC has the firewall 100% disabled
But - The application does not receive the UDP message from the remote device.

**Any suggestions?**

Stated differently:

- This works: Transmit to UPD address (A), Port X - reply from: A, port Y
- This fails: Transmit to UDP address (B), port X - reply from: A, port Y

The second case, the packet seems to be lost inside the bowels of Windows...

Comment: Please show your actual code.  Since the PC has a route between `10.1.1.10` and `10.2.2.10`, and you have verified the PC is actually receiving the reply packets on the network, then your application should be receiving them as well, unless you are `connect()`'ing your UDP socket to `10.3.3.10` specifically, or otherwise filtering the received packets by sender address. I would, however, consider it a bug in the device's implementation that it is not replying using the same interface that received the request.

Comment: Are you using `connect`?

Comment: Not using connect.

Comment: I'm not filtering the data by address

Comment: I'll try changing the device side ... to use the same interface but that is not always an easy thing to do

Comment: Remy - WRT your comment about 'reply using the same interface' - that's not so simple, the underlying solution is LWIP in the device - options there are very limited.  Under Linux, when you recvfrom() you generally do not know the interface. You could - itterate overall interfaces - and open a listen socket, and bind that socket to each interface, then listen on that interface, that port.  I would assume - the "sendto" would then match up with the bound interface.. But that does not exist in Lwip..